# Mysql insert error exception c#

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I'm having an issue with an insert query. I don't know whats wrong with it since the query seems good.

Table buildup:

```
id(auto increment int) | idkooilist(int)|toegang(varchar) |naam(tinyint)
```

Here is the code:

```
MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection("server = localhost; user id = root; password=testpass;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=datanallyspapegaaien");
        myConnection.Open();
        byte boolvalue = new byte();
        if(loc.toegangpubliek==true)
        { boolvalue = 1; }
        else
        {
            boolvalue = 0;
        }

        MySqlCommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();

        myCommand.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO locatie( idkooilist, toegang, naam) VALUES( @idkooilist @toegang, @naam)");
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@idkooilist", MySqlDbType.Int64).Value = (idloctokooi);
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@toegang", MySqlDbType.Byte).Value = boolvalue;
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@naam", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = loc.naam;

        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Here is the error message:

> 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '1, 'Bureau')' at line 1

Comment: The query is not god. You're missing a comma between the first two values.

Comment: And toegang(varchar) is called as a MySqlDbType.Byte which looks iffy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a comma

```
@idkooilist @toegang
```

Add one:

```
@idkooilist, @toegang
```

So it will look like:

```
"INSERT INTO locatie (idkooilist, toegang, naam) VALUES (@idkooilist, @toegang, @naam)"
```